# Nodal analysis of operation amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

How can I calculate the transfer function with nodal analysis?

[image: Schematics]

I tried it with the system of linear equations but it doesn't seem to work:

\$I_{R_1} + I_{R_2} = 0\$ and
\$-I_{R_2} = 0\$

with

\$I_{R_1} = \frac{u_e-u_d}{R_1}\$ and
\$I_{R_2} = \frac{u_a-u_d}{R_2}\$

I get the wrong answer.

Comment: Where did you get "\$-I_{R2}=0\$"? Did you choose an op-amp with infinite output impedance? Because the ones with very low output impedance are much more popular.

Answer (score 2):

The op-amp symbol can sometimes lead one astray as, I believe, it has in this case.

Recall that the output of an ideal op-amp *is an ideal voltage controlled voltage source* which means that *the output will source or sink any amount of current*.

Let's redraw the circuit by replacing the op-amp with an ideal amplifier model:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9V2iT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By voltage division and superposition, we write

$$V_- = V_i \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} + V_o\frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}$$

But, by inspection

$$V_o = A(V_+ - V_-) = -AV_-$$

thus

$$V_o = - \frac{R_2}{R_1 + \frac{R_1 + R_2}{A}}V_i$$

For an ideal op-amp, \$A \rightarrow \infty\$ so

$$V_o = -\frac{R_2}{R_1}V_i $$

Now, this is not the typical method to solve op-amp problems.  However, I hope this gives you some insight into why your initial equations are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Those equations have to be wrong by inspection....

If \$I_{R_1} + I_{R_2} = 0 \$  then\$ -I_{R_2}\$ cannot equal zero else \$I_{R_1}\$ would also equal zero and that's nonsence. Also, if you are going to write equations like this you need to mark on the circuit the presumed direction of those currents.

One fact that you might need to consider is that if the op-amp is configured for negative feedback (which it is) then the voltage at -Vin will be forced (by feedback) to be precisely the same voltage as at +Vin.

As the voltage at +Vin is zero, then the voltage at -Vin is also zero which means the current through R1 (right to left) must be \$\frac{U_e}{R_1}\$.

I'll leave the rest up to the inquisitive to solve.

Comment: Well I have three nodes. One is the ground reference which under the U_d voltage. Then I got one between R1 and R2 and the directions of these two currents go to this node, hence why I thought I_R1 + I_R2 = 0. And then I got the node over U_a which would -I_R2 = 0 and its negative because of its direction.

Comment: Quote: "Vin will be forced (by feedback) to be precisely the same voltage as at +Vin." I would prefer to deleate "precisely" and replace it with "approximately" ("precisely" for infinite open-loop gain only).

Comment: @lvw. I didn't use the word exact because I felt that was too exact LOL

Comment: I dont know where my mistake is

Comment: Your mistake simply is the wrong assumption IR2=0. Instead, IR2 is a finite current driven by Va.

Comment: @Andy, of course, I assume that you know the "secret" behind the diff. input voltage. And - i guess - it is more or less a pedagocical question if we answer using the term "exact" or "nearly/approximately". But since it is one single word only, it is my philosophy from the beginning to be as exact as it seems to be adequate.

Comment: @LvW - what secret LOL?

Comment: Ok so I have now just one linear equation I_R1 + I _R2 = 0, which would be u_e/R_1 + u_a/R_2 = 0. Why can I just ignore u_d is what i dont understand completely?

Comment: Oh I see beacuse vfot the ideal amp u_d would be 0. Thx!

Comment: @craft - correct - for an ideal op-amp you can assume that the action of negative feedback forces both inputs to be at always the same voltage hence Ud is zero.

Comment: @andyaka would there also be just one equation in this network? http://www.amplifier.cd/Tutorial/Uebertragungsfunktion/images/linear-tiefpass-inv-sch.gif

Comment: Or another question: shouldnt I have two equations with nodal analysis?

Comment: @craft - I'm so old that I fail to recognize whether I'm doing nodal analysis, kirchoffs or whatever - I just go for it and get there or fail to get there. Whatever works, works for me. Ask a musicican about what genre they make music in - a lot of them will scowl at you and say something like - does it matter or "I won't be categorized to a genre hence won't comment" etc.. I'm also a musician but I'm trying to give you an honest answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Well for that one i got U_in/R_2 + s*C*U_out + U_out/R_1 = 0 for the node assuming all the currents go towards the node.

Comment: @craft - what is "s*C*U_out". Current thru R1 is the same as current thru R2 because no current flows in to the input -Vin. Current thru R1 is known because -Vin is zero therefore current thru R2 can be easily calculated.

Comment: This would be the capacitor

Comment: There isn't a cap in your question.